# What is the difference between Promise.resolve(thenable) and new Promise(thenable.then)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

The question is the title. I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of promises and I think I've figured out how `Promise.resolve(thenable)` works, or at least mostly how it works, looking at the examples on MDN. I'm wondering if there's a difference between the two. I whipped up this example to show them behaving the same, in way that I would think would show differences in behaviour if there was going to be any. But obviously this test alone isn't good enough to conclude there's nothing different about them, so I've come here.

```js
let thenable = {
    then(resolve) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve((()=>{
                console.log('test');
                return thenable;
            })());
        }, 1000);
    },
};

let p1 = Promise.resolve(thenable);
let p2 = new Promise(thenable.then);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the two work mostly the same. You're right, passing `resolve` and `reject` to the `then` method invocation of a thenable is what basically happens when you are resolving a promise with the thenable object.

However, there are a few differences:

- the `then` method of a thenable is called as a method on (with the `this` context as) the thenable object, unlike your `new Promise(thenable.then)` does - a `.bind(thenable)` would fix that.
- `Promise.resolve` (obviously) has to check first whether the passed object is a thenable at all, it also handles obscure cases where accessing (not calling) `.then` throws
- a subtle discrepance in timing: `Promise.resolve` schedules even the `then` call asynchronously:

  ```
  Promise.resolve({
    get then() {
      console.log("property access");
      return function(res, rej) {
        console.log("method call");
        res("fulfillment");
      };
    }
  }).then(console.log);
  console.log("sync execution end");
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any difference between these two constructs  (`Promise.resolve(thenable)` and `new Promise(thenable.then)`)

- Both support `resolve, reject` as parameters.
- If an error is thrown within the `then(resolve) { ... }` it will be implicitly catched and the promise will be rejected.
- Resolving `then(resolve) { ... }` with `thenable` would result in infinite recursion.

Comment: You add the clarification, "In the way you use them in your example." Which makes me think there are cases where they differ. Could you show an example of when they differ?

Comment: @Mason sorry, what I meant was that there should not be a difference for the case `Promise.resolve(thenable)` and `new Promise(thenable.then)`

Comment: @Mason t.niese is right. There is no difference in output. But avoid to use Promise.resolve to anything other then getting a resolved Promise.